# Accumulate values of Duplicated Element in a List

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

My list consists of elements with fiels Type(`String`), Amount(`Double`) and Quantity(`Integer`) and it looks like this:

```
Type: Type A, Amount : 55.0, Quantity : 0
Type: Type A, Amount : 55.0, Quantity : 5
Type: Type A, Amount : 44.35, Quantity : 6
Type: Type A, Amount : 55.0, Quantity : 0
Type: Type B, Amount : 7.0, Quantity : 1
Type: Type B, Amount : 7.0, Quantity : 1
Type: Type C, Amount : 1613.57, Quantity : 0
Type: Type C, Amount : 1613.57, Quantity : 1
```

So i am trying to loop my array to find duplicate, and add the Amount if its duplicate. The outcome would be like this:

```
Type: Type A, Amount : 209.35.0, Quantity : 11
Type: Type B, Amount : 14.0, Quantity : 2
Type: Type C, Amount : 3227.14, Quantity : 1
```

What i have tried is creating another List, add the List to new List, then compare them, but didnt work

```
List<Type> newList = new ArrayList();

for(int k = 0; k < typeList.size(); k++) {
    Type type= new Type();
    Double totalAmount = Double.parseDouble("0");
    type.setTypeName(typeList.get(k).getTypeName());
    type.setAmount(chargeTypeList.get(k).getAmount());

    newList.add(k, type);

    if(typeList.get(k).getChargeTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(newList.get(k).getiTypeName())) {
        totalAmount += typeList.get(k).getAmount();
    }
}
```

I don't want to hardcode the value to check for duplicate Type

Answer (score 5):

You should probably be putting these values into a Map, which guarantees there is only one element for each key. Using a map is very common for representing amounts of some *thing* where we store the thing as the key and keep track of how many of those things we have in the value.

You can use `compute` to then add elements to the list.

What you currently have:

```
record Data(String type, Double amount, Integer quantity) {}
```

What may represent your data better:

```
record Datav2(Double amount, Integer quantity) {}
```

Storing Datav2 in a map and adding an element.

```
var map = new HashMap<>(Map.of("A", new Datav2( 2.0, 3)));
        
// add element to map equivalent to Data("A", 3.0, 3)
map.compute("A", (k, v) -> {
    if (v == null) {
        v = new Datav2(0.0, 0); 
    }
    return new Datav2(v.amount = 3.0, v.quantity + 3);
});
```

If you need to start with a list for whatever reason you can use the `Stream` API to turn the list into a map. Specifically [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).

```
var list = List.of(new Data("A", 2.0, 3),
       new Data("A", 3.0, 3),
       new Data("C", 2.0, 1),
       new Data("B", 10.0, 3),
       new Data("B", 2.0, 5)
);

var collected = list
         .stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       // what will the key be
                       Data::type,
                       // what will the value be
                       data -> new Datav2(data.amount, data.quantity),
                       // how do we combine two values if they have the same key
                       (d1, d2) -> new Datav2(d1.amount + d2.amount, d1.quantity + d2.quantity)
         ));
System.out.println(collected);
```

> {A=Datav2[amount=5.0, quantity=6], B=Datav2[amount=12.0, quantity=8], C=Datav2[amount=2.0, quantity=1]}

Comment: Good, but it is worth to point out that with this approach, many intermediate instances of `Datav2` (which eventually would not be needed) would be allocated in memory. When the input is massive, it would have impact on the memory consumption and on the performance as well.

Comment: There would be *less* total memory consumption using a Map than a List (as we have fewer elements). Converting from a List to a Map could be expensive - but if memory overhead is key then you should not be using that List in the first place (and should also be using primitives in our records). I've edited the `compute` to use mutation instead of a new object.

Comment: I forgot java records are shallowly immutable - reverted edit.

Comment: *"would be less total memory consumption using a Map than a List"* what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sure, can't change a record's properties, they are immutable data-carries.

Comment: @Alexander if you never used a List to hold that data, the Map would always take up less or equal space when compared to the List containing the same information. If multiple elements have the same `type` you can store them in a single `Datav2` under a map, but must be stored in two seperate `Data`'s in a List. (they take up equal space (give or take map overhead) if all `types` in the List are unique)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249306/discussion-between-marcus-dunn-and-alexander-ivanchenko).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to sort the list by type, then iterate it and add each item to an sum item. When the type changes, add your sum item to a result list and keep going.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for achieving is by use of collect & hashmap's merge operation:

```
    List<TypeClass> ls = List.of(new TypeClass("A", 12.3, 2), new TypeClass("A", 3.4, 4),
            new TypeClass("B", 12.4, 6), new TypeClass("B", 12.8, 8));

    System.out.println(
            ls.stream().collect(HashMap<String, TypeClass>::new, (x, y) -> x.merge(y.getTypeName(), y, (o, p) -> {
                return new TypeClass(y.getTypeName(), o.getAmount() + p.getAmount(),
                        o.getQuantity() + p.getQuantity());
            }), (a, b) -> a.putAll(b)));
```

this will print following output:

> {A=TypeClass [typeName=A, amount=15.700000000000001, quantity=6],
> B=TypeClass [typeName=B, amount=25.200000000000003, quantity=14]}

Here, we are accumulating hashmap which is merged based on key i.e. your string value. Merged function is simple addition of amount & quantity of your Type Class.

Comment: The `combiner` function is broken (*the third argument of `collect()`*), it's not capable of merging partial results properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in collector `groupingBy()` to group the objects having the same `type` in conjunction with a custom collector created via `Collector.of()` as downstream of grouping.

Assuming that your custom object looks like this (*for the purpose of conciseness, I've used a Java 16 record*):

```
public record MyType(String type, double amount, int quantity) {}
```

**Note:**

- Don't use wrapper-types without any good reason, uses primitives instead. That would allow avoiding unnecessary *boxing/unboxing* and eliminates the possibilities of getting a `NullPointerException` while performing arithmetical operations or comparing numeric values.
- If the number values that `type` attribute might have is limited, then it would be better to use an `enum` instead of `String` because it's more reliable (it would guard you from making a typo) and offers some extra possibilities since enums have an extensive language support.

That's how the accumulation logic can be implemented:

```
List<MyType> typeList = new ArrayList();
        
List<MyType> newList = typeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyType::type,
        Collector.of(
            MyAccumulator::new,
            MyAccumulator::accept,
            MyAccumulator::merge
        )
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new MyType(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().getAmount(), entry.getValue().getQuantity()))
    .toList();
```

And that's how the custom accumulation type internally used by the collector might look like:

```
public static class MyAccumulator implements Consumer<MyType> {
    private double amount;
    private int quantity;

    @Override
    public void accept(MyType myType) {
        add(myType.amount(), myType.quantity());
    }
    
    public MyAccumulator merge(MyAccumulator other) {
        add(other.amount, other.quantity);
        return this;
    }
    
    private void add(double amount, int quantity) {
        this.amount += amount;
        this.quantity += quantity;
    }

    // getters
}
```